# Software/Webapp for creating computer science diagrams

Tags: data-structures, diagram

What are some good programs or web-based applications that can be used (preferably, but not necessarily, for free) to create diagrams for computer science articles or dissertations?

Particularly, I'm looking to represent data structures such as stacks, linked lists, trees, etc..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/) should work for you. Many of the student's in my class used it and it worked out great.
- Microsoft Visio: Not web based, but quite powerful
- Dia: Open source diagramming tool

Answer (score 5):

I made [zwibbler.com](http://zwibbler.com) for this. For a formal article, turn down the "sloppiness" setting.

Answer (score 4):

[OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/)

Answer (score 4):

For sequence diagrams try: http://websequencediagrams.com/

Answer (score 3):

[draw.io](https://www.draw.io), which I work on, is [open source](https://github.com/jgraph/draw.io), free to use online with integrations to Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox and Github.

There's also [Desktop electron versions for Window, mac and Linux](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases)

Comment: Uh, this is excellent. Seriously underrated comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of diagrams you mean, but I've always found [wolframalpha](http://wolframalpha.com) useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found PowerPoint to do a surprisingly good job

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing your article or dissertation in LaTeX, have a look at the [TikZ package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ). It allows you to make the type of diagrams usually required in computer science with a few, well-readable commands.

- Here are [some examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/),
- here is [the project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) (although it might already be included in your TeX distribution) and
- here is [the manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

[yEd](http://www.yworks.com/yed) is really well suited for this: Java based, and thus runs on almost any platform. It can export vector graphics (SVG, PS, PDF) and thus  is great for printed documents and also offers automatic layout algorithms that will really help you with the arrangement of trees and other graph structures. Also it has a very intuitive interface and of course it is free.